# Tracking History of changes in Custom fields of custom objects

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, history-tracking, field-history

I want to track the history of 5 fields in custom object. I have selected the Track History checkbox against the corresponding fields in Custom Fields & Relationships section of the object.Still,changes in respective fields are not getting tracked. Is there anything I am missing here ?

Comment: what type of field(s) are they? you cant track Formula, roll-up summary, auto-number fields, Created By or Last Modified By

Comment: @glls They are number fields. Also,changes from none of the users are getting tracked.

Comment: Have you added the related list?

Comment: @Tushar Sharma Thanks! Yes, I forgot to add the related list.Instead I was checking in field activity history.

Comment: @PankajAndhale Then you can accept my answer and close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as confirmed in comments you need to add the related list to page layout. The name will be something like "ObjectName History Related List".

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have followed these steps

1. Enable **Track Field History** option under option feature on the Custom object.
2. Click Set History Tracking in the Custom Fields & Relationships section and checked all those fields for tracking.
3. Add Custom object History related list on the detail page.

Comment: Yes same steps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My mistake was that I forgot check Track Field History in the object settings. So for view field history you should do these steps:

1. Check 'Track Field History' in the OBJECT settings:[image]

2. Open Fields and Relationship -> Set History Tracking.
3. Add 'YourObjectName History' related list to page layout